# Insert Network User Pass In PHP

Tags: php

I use below code, to access network files

```
$network = array(
        '0-100' => '//192.168.1.30/public');
```

When this computer (192.168.1.30) do not have password my code work good. but, when set username and password for that computer (192.168.1.30) ,i do not know how insert user and pass in my php code to access network shared folders and files

Comment: What file sharing protocol do you use ?

Comment: i use windows and wampserver

Answer (score 0):

Try `//<user>:<pwd>@192.168.1.30/public`. More [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax).

Comment: i try repository = array(
        '0-1000000' => '//jim:123456@192.168.1.5/Users/MEHDI/Desktop');   and   repository = array(
        '0-1000000' => '//<jim>:<123456>@192.168.1.5/Users/MEHDI/Desktop');   but do not work  :(